# Typescript initialize empty object

Tags: typescript

I'm learning about typescript, and I'm struggling with this code below.

```js
      const profile = state.currentProfile;
      type literalProfile = keyof Partial<Omit<Profile, 'id'>>;

      const values: Record<literalProfile, string | undefined> = {
        name: '',
        avatar: '',
        title: '',
        subtitle: '',
      };

      Object.entries(data).forEach((entry) => {
        const key = entry[0] as literalProfile;
        const value = entry[1];
        if (value && profile[key] !== value) {
          values[key] = value;
        }
      });

      await this.$axios.patch(`/users/profiles/${profile.id}`, values);
```

The question is, Is there any way to initialize values as an empty object, like this?

```js
const values: Record<literalProfile, string | undefined> = {};
```

Because if I do something like this typescript highlight me an error

> Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'Record<"name" | "title" | "subtitle" | "avatar", string | undefined>': name, title, subtitle, avatar

If I try something like this

```js
let values: Record<literalProfile, string | undefined>;
```

Then typescript says

> Variable 'values' is used before being assigned.

In this line

```js
await this.$axios.patch(`/users/profiles/${profile.id}`, values);
```

So I don't know how to fix that, any ideas?

Comment: An empty object is not a valid value of that type, as it lacks the required properties.  Perhaps you want `Partial<Record<literalProfile, string>>`?  Or a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) to temporarily lie to the compiler about the type of the object while you initialize it?  Either way I would prefer to see a [mcve] here suitable for dropping into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play) to demonstrate the issue for myself. A self-contained toy example without axios would be nice.

Comment: [Playground Link](http://shorturl.at/yJLT3) Your solution with Partial works great, I don't know why I don't realized about this solution. Despite, I would like to know what solution is more common practice among typescript developers, your solution or @wex solution. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, you're using `Record<listeralProfile, string | undefined>`.

Instead, you should use `{ [key in literalProfile]?: string }`.

There's a subtle difference. Both support `undefined` as a value, but by using the optional field keyword `?` you can omit those fields when initializing your object.

```
const values: { [key in literalProfile]?: string } = {};
```

Comment: Your solution works as expected, but I would like to know where I can read about the difference of your solution and Partial solution as @jcalz mentioned. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wrapping your object in `Partial` basically adds the optional keyword to each field. You can read more here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype

Comment: In your case, it actually shouldn't make a difference which you use since every field is possibly an `undefined` value anyway.